# web Api application subscribing to a queue. Is it a good idea?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, microservices, restful-architecture, event-bus

We are designing a reporting system using microservice architecture. All the services are supposed to be subscribers to the event bus and they communicate by raising events. We also decided to expose each of our services using REST api. Now the question is , is it a good idea to create our services as web api [RESTful] applications which are also subscribers to the event bus? so basically there are 2 ponits of entry to each service - api and events. I have a feeling that we should separate out these 2 as these are 2 different concerns. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since Microservices architecture are Un-opinionated software design. So you may get different answers on this questions.
Yes, REST and Event based are two different things but sometime both combined gives design to achieve better flexibility.

Answering to your concerns, **I don't see any harm if REST APIs also subscribe to a queue**  as long as you can maintain both of them i.e changes to message does not have any impact of APIs and you have proper fallback and [Eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) mechanism in place. you can check [discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331101/relationship-between-restful-uris-and-pubsub-topics) . There are already few project which tried it such as [nakadi](https://github.com/zalando/nakadi) and [ponte](https://github.com/eclipse/ponte).

**So It all depends on your service's communication behaviour to choose between REST APIs and Event-Based design Or Both**.

What you do is based on your  requirement you can choose **REST APIs** where you see **synchronous behaviour** between services 
and go with **Event based design** where you find services needs **asynchronous behaviour**, there is no harm combining both also.

Ideally for inter-process communication protocol it is better to go with messaging and for client-service REST APIs are best fitted.
Check the Communication style in [microservices.io](http://microservices.io/)

**REST based Architecture**

- Advantage

  1. Request/Response is easy and best fitted when you need synchronous environments.
  2. Simpler system since there in no intermediate broker
  3. Promotes orchestration i.e Service can take action based on response of other service.
- Drawback

  1. Services needs to discover locations of service instances.
  2. One to one Mapping between services.
  3. Rest used HTTP which is general purpose protocol built on top of TCP/IP which adds enormous amount of overhead when using it to pass messages.

**Event Driven Architecture**

- Advantage

  1. Event-driven architectures are appealing to API developers because they function very well in asynchronous environments.
  2. Loose coupling since it decouples services as on a event of once service multiple services can take action based on application requirement. it is easy to plug-in any new consumer to producer.
  3. Improved availability since the message broker buffers messages until the consumer is able to process them.
- Drawback

  1. Additional complexity of message broker, which must be highly available
  2. Debugging an event request is not that easy.

Comment: Thanks for you response, Although very informative but your response didn't answer my question. Probably it is more an implementation type of questions versus design which I rephrase it this way. I want to implement my services to be both Rest and Event based. Now can I put both in a single project so just one process is handling both Rest and Events?

Comment: Hi @ssnkh, Thanks for reply. I have updated the answer and also still keeping design consideration as it can help someone going through such consideration.

Comment: Hi @YogendraMishra have you ended up doing it in a single app? I have an API based microservice but was thinking about making it also to listen to RabbitMQ. To me it sounds like it may bring more troubles than goods.